# Does a Javascriptable FTP Upload Java/Flash Applet exist?

Tags: java, javascript, flash, ftp, applet

To be able to upload large files from a HTML page to a FTP server, I am looking for a Java/Flash FTP upload applet.

I really like the way [dhtmlxVault](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxVault/index.shtml) works, but I need it to upload to a FTP server instead of a HTTP file upload.

It would be really nice if the applet has no GUI of it's own, but instead is fully scriptable using Javascript so I can use HTML/CSS for it's appearance.

I hopefully looked into [Yahoo!'s YUI Uploader](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/uploader/) since it requires Flash, but the documentation only mentions HTTP upload and no FTP upload.

Comment: What is the reason behind requiring FTP and not HTTP upload?

Would the following process not work:
1. Upload via HTTP to holding location (stores file+meta data)
2. Run server-side process to FTP file to correct location

Comment: I did consider exactly the solution you suggested. But, the main reason for needing FTP is the size of the files in question which can be hundreds of megabytes. This exceeds largely the maximum allowed post size in PHP (which I want to use server side), and available webspace will also be limited.

Comment: I was documenting an application when I used the word 'Javascriptable'. Upon realising what I had written, I then began Googling to see if it was even a word - or at least a commonly used non-word. Thus leading me here.

Is Javascriptable a word?!

Comment: Yes, 'Javascriptable' is a word, and I invented it :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what [IntegralFTP](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/integralftp/overview.html) is - a Java applet wrapped by Javascript. The GUI is all implemented in Javascript, and so you can change it how you like.

It supports SFTP, FTP and FTPS.

You can use IntegralFTP from http://www.integralftp.com, or purchase from [here](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/integralftp/purchase.html).

Answer (score 1):

I tried the [ZUpload](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zupload/) Java applet.

Pro's:

- The user interface works as easy as I could hope it to work.
- It is a Java applet with it's own GUI, but I was able to implement some Javascript callbacks in it to update progress information in HTML. I would be able to minimize the GUI further.

Con's:

- When an upload failes (when the FTP server tells it it is to busy, please retry in a moment) it thinks the upload succeeded and goes on with the next file. I tried to catch the exceptions but was unable to do so because of either the way j-ftp is used in the applet or my own lack of knowledge.
- The project seems to be dead since 2003, so I don't expect any updates.

So my conclusion it that it is not ready to be used in a production environment. I still need a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, any swing app would work with only small modifications if you have access to the code. If your ready to offer an applet, maybe you could even use java web start (would require even less changes).

Answer (score 0):

What about this one (seems to be opensource)?
http://jupload.sourceforge.net/applet-basic-picture.html