# open source java FTP client library

Tags: java, open-source, ftp-client

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Java FTP client library should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295178/what-java-ftp-client-library-should-i-use)

I am looking for open source FTP client library which exposes APIsI.I will be calling these APis from my java program .The APIs should return proper codes indicating whether the while was successfully downloaded  etc.In case or error it should return proper error codes.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at *Apache Commons Net*, http://commons.apache.org/net/

It implements many internet protocols, among them is ftp.