# Download picture via FTP with Java

Tags: java, authentication, ftp, image

I would need to download pictures from a FTP server (who needs login/passwod authentification) via my java application. What is the most efficient way to do it ?

Thank you very much.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a suitable Java FTP client library. A topic that has been previously discussed here:

[What Java FTP client library should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295178/what-java-ftp-client-library-should-i-use)

The exact manner of downloading a file from the FTP server will vary a bit depending on the library you choose.

Answer (score 0):

try using [apache-commons-net](http://commons.apache.org/net/) api, its quick and simple.

here is a [sample on how to use commons-net](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/UsetheFTPClient.htm)