# Taking a picture from IP camera and upload using FTP

Tags: java, image, ftp, camera

I would like to write a program in Java which takes pictures from an IP camera and sends (over ftp) it to a website, replacing an old image.

Does anyone know any libraries I can use for that task?

I think the main problem will be grabbing an image from IP camera and saving it as a JPEG. 
Basically I have never worked with cameras before. So I will be really grateful if someone can give me some tips.

Comment: Besides JMF and OpenCV for Java, VLCJ, a Java binding to libVLC can also stream from an IP camera or even a web camera and save a snapshot of its stream in JPEG or PNG. After that is just a matter of finding the right FTP client Java library.

Answer (score 0):

First you would have to figure out how to get the data from IP Camera you will be using. Good starting point can be found here: http://dragosc.itmcd.ro/uncategorized/java-media-framework-vs-ip-camera-jpegmjpeg-complete-overview-sources/

Second, you should choose the library for ftp communication, this topic was discussed here:
[What Java FTP client library should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295178/what-java-ftp-client-library-should-i-use)

Once you'll write smth which actually does something you can get back to SO and ask more specific questions.