# Is it possible to modify a html file, from which the script is called, using JS?

Tags: javascript, file, editor, text-editor, client-side

I'm developing the following for local use:

I've got a HTML page, with some content.

Is it possible to edit the content of this HTML through the browser, and save the changes on-the-fly to this same file using only JavaScript? So the users could edit the file through the browser and it would auto-save itself.

The problem is, I have no possibility to use server-side languages here. It should be compatible with the latest Firefox, other browsers aren't important.

Comment: @Alin, you can generate pages only with javascript and with data coming from various sources. Especially for the browser he targets.

Comment: Must have been blind at the moment. I missed the first line... "I'm developing the following for local use".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you can't save server-side files using only native Javascript.

However, there seem to be some Java FTP Applets around that are scriptable from JavaScript. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285237/does-a-javascriptable-ftp-upload-java-flash-applet-exist).

Other than that, you need something on the server side receiving and writing the data.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible without backend code.

Comment: It was not possible until recently, since some browsers now support the [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API).

Answer (score 2):

If the changes are only for that user, you can parse the data of the page and store them locally. Using some of the HTML5 goodies: http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/storage.html

Then, when the user comes back, render it with a Javascript template engine.
My heart goes to [PURE](http://beebole.com/pure) but there's plenty of other options if you prefer the double brackets family of templates.

If the changes are for all users, you could call a third server you own(appEngine, Amazon,...), to store the data, and deliver them through JSONP. And again render them with a JS template engine.